# weired thing, GAE can load .ico but not for .png

Tags: google-app-engine

I have two files under root directory, they are `fav.ico` and `fav.png`, and the app.yaml is like this:

```
handlers:
- url: /fav\.ico
  static_files: fav.ico
  upload: fav\.ico

- url: /fav\.png
  static_files: fav.png
  upload: fav\.png
```

The most weired thing is that I can load the `fav.ico` while fail in loading `fav.png`, since two files share a same settings, I can't figure out what has happened.

html is declared as below:

```
<img src="/fav.png">
<img src="/fav.ico">
```

=============Update==============

I haven't deployed it to GAE, just under developed enviroment. For png, there is no effect at all, and the log is `default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 154`

Comment: How can you tell that they aren't loading? Observed (lack of) effect? Application logs?

Comment: @DaveW.Smith I add more infomation

Comment: If the logs show no attempt to GET either file, I'd suspect the HTML. Can you show us more context around the <img> tags?